# Behind the scenes property of Winforms listbox item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

So I'm going back and cleaning up code I did years ago. In one part, (and I used this several times) I have a list box displaying employee names such as

Smith, John
Doe, Jane

When the user clicks the name, I do something like

```
String unBrokenName = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
String LastName = unBrokenName.Substring(...
```

You get the idea, I extract the first and last name based upon the ", " 
Then I do this to get the employee from the sql database.

```
Employee SelectedEmployee = Employee.GetEmployeeByFirstLast(FirstName, LastName);
```

At the time, it was the best I knew. Now it feels wrong, because I KNOW I should be able to get the sql ID of the employee when they select it, like

```
int EmployeeId = SOMELISTBOXSELECTEDITEMPROPERTY;
Employee SelectedEmployee = Employee.GetEmployeeByID(EmployeeId);
```

Is there some property for a listbox item that will store this id while displaying the same name the users are used to seeing?

Comment: Right after I posted this, I realized I could probably override the listbox and create something custom, but that still leaves me wondering if something already exists that I don't know about.

Comment: Your items can be *something* (a class) what has `ToString()` overriden, but will contain all data you may need when operating with items.

Comment: How do you set the data source of ListBox1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually add anything you'd like to a listbox:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
listBox1.Items.Add( new Foo() { Id = 101, Name = "Foo Bar" } );
listBox1.Items.Add( new Foo() { Id = 102, Name = "Foo Bar Jr." } );
```

The `SelectedItem` property will now give you the selected `Foo`, while displaying the `Name` property in the list itself.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Foo item = ( listBox1.SelectedItem as Foo );
    if( item != null )
    {
        // use item.Id here
    }
}
```

Instead of overriding `ToString`, you can also use the `DisplayMember` property of the listbox to select which property the listbox will display.

Comment: I never knew this. I was using listboxes for years and just thought they were just showing a list of strings. I've been doing so much more work than I ever needed.

Comment: Hehe, I know that feeling.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
listBox1.DataSource = employeesList;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "LastName";
listBox1.ValueMember = "EmployeeId";
```

When you run your application the listbox will have the list of employees that you are passing and it will show the `LastName`. But when you select an item, you can access the id by:

```
`listBox1.SelectedValue();`
```

And then in the `listbox1_Click` event something like:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    int employeeId = listBox1.SelectedValue();
    //do something here;       
}
```

Comment: I like this answer just as much as Chris's, I've always overlooked the display vs value member. I've marked his as the accepted answer simply because he took it a step further and showed me how to return a whole class. Thanks a lot!